# Unit testing : how could I keep value of an attribute defined in __init__

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm testing my code but I have an attribute error that I'm unable to resolve myself.

```
import os

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.folder = os.environ.get('folder')

    def a(self):
        myFolder = self.folder
        return myFolder

    @staticmethod
    def b():
        myData = MyClass.a(MyClass)
        return myData
```

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from myclass import MyClass

@patch.dict('os.environ', {'folder': 'blabla'})
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def testB(self):
        myclass = MyClass()
        content = myclass.b()
```

I have an Attribute Error inside 'a' myFolder = self.folder : 'type object MyClass has no attribute folder'

How could I do (without mocking result of a() ) ?

Comment: Where does @staticfunction come from? It's not in py-3.8

Comment: Sorry, it was @staticmethod :)

Comment: Isn't your issue simply reproducible without unittest, with just: `import myclass; x=myclass.MyClass.b()`?

Comment: It seems to me that you want folder to be a "class variable", i.e. its value is shared by all instances. Can you confirm?